# Full screen mode for displaying videos using VideoView

Tags: android

I want to play videos using VideoView in Android fullscreen mode.

When I am playing in portrait mode, the video is occupying only 1/4 of the screen.
When I am playing the video in landscape mode , the video is occupying about 3/4th of the screen.

My question is how can I disable the automatic scaling of the video when using the VideoView.

Also, I created a class extending VideoView & then overridden the onMeasure() .

But how can I use the class in another class which extends Activity.

I have searched a lot on Internet & unable to get  a proper code.

Answer (score 3):

Apply the following layout format over the xml containing the videoview it will for sure will play the video in full screen mode. as it is running mine :) Hope it helps

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

My application force closes when I added the following lines:

```
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

It was already showing warning with each of the above lines